How to nest a static library in a static library project in Visual Studio
I have a c++ project in Visual Studio to create a static library. I need to modify it in order to use another external static library (in the specific this library is NLopt).
If my project was a generating a executable file, than it was easy because it was enough to point to the library in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies , but because it is generating a static library, the linker is not present in the project properties.
Could you explain me what's the correct procedure?
